# Test cases getting failed when trying to do with mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I am trying simple test cases using mocha framework

I have written simple typescript

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(width, height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    get height() {
        return this.height;
    }

    set height(value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            throw new Error('"height" must be a number.');
        }

        this.height = value;
    }

    get width() {
        return this.width;
    }

    set width(value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'number') {
            throw new Error('"width" must be a number.');
        }

        this.width = value;
    }


    get area() {
        return this.width * this.height;
    }


    get circumference() {
        return 2 * this.width + 2 * this.height;
    }
}

var rectangle= new Rectangle(10,20);
module.exports = Rectangle;
```

but when trying to write test case as below:

```
"use strict"
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015']
});
// Import chai.
import * as chai from 'chai';
var path = require('path');

// Import the Rectangle class.
let Rectangle = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'rectangle.js'));
const should = chai.should;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe('Rectangle', () => {
    describe('#width', () => {
        let rectangle;

        beforeEach(() => {
            // Create a new Rectangle object before every test.
            rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        });

        it('returns the width', () => {
            // This will fail if "rectangle.width" does
            // not equal 10.
            rectangle.width.should.equal(10);
        });

    });
});
```

but the test case is failing

[image]

I dont understand the error here

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the [docs for Should](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should) you'll see this:

> var should = require('chai').should() //**actually call the function**

So your code needs to look like this:

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
...
const should = chai.should();
```

Also, there's no need to use the `path` in your case, you should be able to just do:

```
let Rectangle = require('../rectangle.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are showing is due to infinite recursion. You should name the variable that holds the actual value of setters and getters *differently* from the setters and getters themselves. Here's an example with `width`:

```
class Rectangle {
    private _width: number;

    constructor(width: number) {
        this._width = width;
    }

    get width(): number {
        return this._width;
    }

    set width(value: number) {
        this._width = value;
    }
}

const rectangle = new Rectangle(10);

console.log(rectangle.width);
rectangle.width = 100;
console.log(rectangle.width);
// Cannot do this, as it won't compile: rectangle.width = "platypus";
```

Otherwise, with your code, when the constructor does `this.width = ...`, the setter is invoked, which does `this.width = ...` which invokes the setter again, and again, and again, ...

[Nitzan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445086/1906307) is correct that you must *call* `chai.should()`, not just access it.